TV show (Canadian?) about high school girl who plans a unicorn business
It was about this insane high school girl who was completely scatter-brained and had crazy ideas. She dressed like she was crazy and had frizzy brown hair and maybe glasses. 
The entire show was based on her promising herself she would make a company about or around a unicorn and it seemed to be a documentary of sorts. 
Every single episode opens with her sitting in class and annoying the same teacher until he switches classes. The girl has a blonde male best friend who has either one or two other friends who she hangs out with and the main best friend has a younger sister and weird parents who love the girl and think they should date. There are episodes like when they get locked in their high school and one of her friends falls for the mean popular girl when they all think they are being attacked or something. Then there's one episode where she looses a ring in a cement mixer. And one where she helps her BFF get tickets for his parents anniversary and they have to dress up as punk rockers. In another episode, one of her friends tries to beat a drumming record and starts a band. And there's also an episode where she makes over a scary girl and helps her be nice, but it ends up not working, so they let her do her. And in one episode, the main guy thinks the girl likes him because she keeps asking what he likes but she's actually throwing him a surprise birthday party.
It was most likely Canadian and the theme song is her standing on the screen with a long purple line winding and flipping in and out like a phone cord and she has a really odd name.

Hi! welcome to Movies & TV! Hope we can help you figure out the show. Thanks for all the detail. First, is there any chance you can remember roughly when you saw it/when you think it may have come out? (Even a rough guess - '80s, '90s, etc.) Second, could you clarify what you mean by "create a company around a unicorn"? Do you mean she wants to start a business with a unicorn logo? And third, when you say "they think they are being attacked" - do you remember by who or what? Was this a sci-fi/fantasy show with monsters? Or just a regular show with a "regular" person attacking them? Thanks!

Sounds like the Canadian teen comedy Debra! that aired for one season in 2011.

Debra! (originally Decidedly Debra!) is a Canadian television series that focuses on 14-year-old Debra Delong, who wants to make her own company and wants to run it with [her best friend,] a boy named Preston Lunford.

Debra is quirky, has frizzy brown hair and glasses and calls her company The Magical Flying Pony. Here's the intro, that indeed features that purple line:



